# * Unrecognized field at: database Did you mean?: - metrics - server - logging - DROPWIZARD

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, yaml, dropwizard

I cannot start my dropwizard application after add database details in my application configuration file (server.yml).

**server.yml (app config file)**

```
server:
  applicationConnectors:
  - type: http 
    port: 8080
  adminConnectors:
  - type: http
    port: 9001

database:
  # the name of your JDBC driver
  driverClass: org.postgresql.Driver

  # the username
  user: dbuser

  # the password
  password: pw123

  # the JDBC URL
  url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost/database

  # any properties specific to your JDBC driver:
  properties:
    charSet: UTF-8

  # the maximum amount of time to wait on an empty pool before throwing an exception
  maxWaitForConnection: 1s

  # the SQL query to run when validating a connection's liveness
  validationQuery: "/* MyService Health Check */ SELECT 1"

  # the timeout before a connection validation queries fail
  validationQueryTimeout: 3s

  # the minimum number of connections to keep open
  minSize: 8

  # the maximum number of connections to keep open
  maxSize: 32

  # whether or not idle connections should be validated
  checkConnectionWhileIdle: false

  # the amount of time to sleep between runs of the idle connection validation, abandoned cleaner and idle pool resizing
  evictionInterval: 10s

  # the minimum amount of time an connection must sit idle in the pool before it is eligible for eviction
  minIdleTime: 1 minute
```

As result of run dropwizard application I can see:

```
has an error:
  * Unrecognized field at: database
    Did you mean?:
      - metrics
      - server
      - logging
```

Answer (score 22):

In addition to code given by dropwizard example you need to add a setter for database property.

```
@Valid
@NotNull
@JsonProperty("database")
private DataSourceFactory database = new DataSourceFactory();

public DataSourceFactory getDataSourceFactory() {
    return database;
}

public void setDatabase(DataSourceFactory database) {
    this.database = database;
}
```

Comment: thanks! it worked, this answer should be marked as correct

Comment: I am having the same error, but for the server part of yml: "Unrecognized field at: http"

How should I implement the configuration class properties for this part?

Thank you.

Answer (score 13):

In your application configuration java file, you have to add the matching property for "database". If the properties you're specifying are the standard ones (which they look to be, good!) then you can keep with the `DataSourceFactory` type:

```
public class ExampleConfiguration extends Configuration {
    @Valid
    @NotNull
    @JsonProperty
    private DataSourceFactory database = new DataSourceFactory();

    public DataSourceFactory getDataSourceFactory() {
        return database;
    }

    public void setDatabase(DataSourceFactory database) {
        this.database = database;
    }
}
```

Example here: http://www.dropwizard.io/0.9.0/docs/manual/jdbi.html

Comment: Didn't worked for me :( I already have getter for my fields still facing the issue

Comment: Perhaps check the linked documentation page? Things may have changed since this answer... Looks like they may require JsonProperty annotations now (or perhaps the example just specifies it).

Comment: This won't work on its own - the setter also needs to be present. Add a setter and this will work perfectly.